# Why is dividing double values returning null?

Tags: java, null, double, divide

In Jaspersoft Studio I have tried the following expression.  I am getting null but I don't understand why.  This should be as simple as 3.00/2 and display 1.50 however it is not working it still shows null.  I have confirmed that the fields contain values for all fields.

The expression I am using is as follows:

```
new Double($V{UnitPrice}.doubleValue() == 0 ? 0 : ($F{Price Qty}.doubleValue()/$F{Price}.doubleValue()))
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `UnitPrice` in your division? Your zero check is checking a different value to the one you're using

Comment: What language is that? $V{UnitPrice}.doubleValue() doesn't look like java to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `Double` for your arithmetic, why not use the `compareTo(Double anotherDouble)`?

Not sure if this is the source of your trouble, but it could be the `==` behaving in a way that you did not intend it to and returning `false` hence, the zero...